# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null error

Tags: javascript

I'm writing this code for a website but the error 'Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null' keeps appering:

```
const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
const menuLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');

const mobileMenu = () => {
  menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
  menuLinks.classList.toggle('active');
};

menu.addEventListener ('click', mobileMenu);
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('#mobile-menu')` is null .. load the javascript AFTER the HTML (end of body tag) rather than before ... or wait for DOMContentLoaded event to fire

Comment: I think you made all newbie's mistake, you put your js script in the HTML head part ...

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the others in the comments, you put the script before the elements you want to select. In order to be able to select the elements, you will need to either place the script at the bottom of the page or place a listener to execute the script when the page loads.

**Example:** *In the example I'm posting, you can also put your script at the top of the page or at the bottom ... it just won't matter*

```html
<script>
    // 1. First declare the variables
    let menu, menuLinks;
    // 2. The DOMContentLoaded event fires when the initial HTML
    //    document has been completely loaded and parsed, 
    //    without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
        menuLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');
        menu.addEventListener('click', mobileMenu);
    });

    // 3. Click function
    const mobileMenu = () => {
        menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
        menuLinks.classList.toggle('active');
        console.log('Click is OK!');
    };
</script>


<button id="mobile-menu">Click me!</button>
<div class="navbar__menu"></div>
```

**Example 2:**

Whenever possible, the creation of global variables should be avoided. So for me, Example 2 is a better solution.

```html
<script>
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        let menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
        let menuLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');
        menu.addEventListener('click', function () {
            menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
            menuLinks.classList.toggle('active');
            console.log('Click is OK!');
        });
    });
</script>


<button id="mobile-menu">Click me!</button>
<div class="navbar__menu"></div>
```